# angular js $routeParam not working properly

Tags: angularjs, routeparams

i have used $routeProvide to redirect page from one page to another and in that i am passing some dynamic parameters in url.

it working at one place and not working with another place.

my code : in app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: "client/home/home.html",
                controller: "IndexCtrl",
                access: {
                    isloggedIn: false
                }
            }) 
            .when('/test/:searchTerm', {
                templateUrl: "client/test.html",
                controller: "testController",
                access: {
                    isloggedIn: false
                } 
            })
            .when('/test2/:id', {
                templateUrl: "client/index.html",
                controller: "indexController",
                access: {   
                    isloggedIn: true
                }
            }) 

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });
}]);
```

in controllers file : for testController when i hit url 
server.com/#/test/45 got in console 45 and for indexController when i hit url server.com/#/test2/45 then i get :id in console.

```
app.controller("testController", ['$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
 console.log($routeParams.searchTerm); //get result 45
}]);

app.controller("indexController", ['$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
 console.log($routeParams.id); //get result :id
}]);
```

why this happen can anyone help? and what should be the issue?

Comment: is the url path '/test2/:id' denoted is correct?

Comment: share your html also

Comment: @ebinmanuva l have put only test text in both html and both are exists in location

Comment: @ABUdhay yes it is

Comment: @Nitin  try tying your link straight in address bar, what is the result ?

Comment: @ebinmanuval it returns me as  /test2/:id

Comment: I don't what the problem with  isloggedIn: true that was making error in mycase i have replace true by false then it working
i have redirected my page if not login for that significance it is used
but becuase of this thing the problem was i can't accept

any one know why that parameter created problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `($routeParams.id);` instead of `($routParams.id);`, I don't know why your `$routParams.searchTerm` is working, but it shouldn't (should be `route`, not `rout`).

Comment: i have used $routeParams in my case.. it was just misspelled . thanks for point me there i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is correct, other than the spelling mistake. The only difference i can find is that the IsLoggedIn property value. Did you try by making it false?. And what is the significance of IsLoggedIn property.

Comment: In my case i have used extra parameter for access based if some pages are only used by login user  for that when i am trying to do that i am logged in my system

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?. And could you please share the html of index.html

Answer (score 0):

check your `hyperlink` to the route `/test2/:id`.
It may be like `ng-href="#/test2/:id"`
change it to `ng-href="#/test2/{{id}}"`

---

don't forgot to define variable `id`

recreated the issue in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/qtfxs5wd/)